# Remove parent div in a HTML string but keep contents

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following HTML before in a string in my JS file that has jQuery available to use. How would I remove the `'fr-wrapper'` div, and also remove the `'fr-element'` div but leave the inner contents?

**Original:**

```
<div class="pixer content row fr-box fr-inline">
        <div class="fr-wrapper" dir="auto">
            <div aria-disabled="false" class="fr-element fr-view" contenteditable="true" dir="auto" spellcheck="false">
                <div class="top-mid-float">
                    <div id="main-inner-header">
                        <h1><strong>Hello there!</strong></h1>
                    </div>
                    <div id="lower-content-header">
                        <p>Quisque tincidunt nunc in lacus consectetur, et pharetra velit pulvinar. Quisque id egestas tellus, vitae venenatis tellus. Etiam accumsan iaculis sem, in vestibulum odio tincidunt vel. Etiam justo massa, congue vulputate dui.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**What I'm aiming for:**

```
<div class="pixer content row fr-box fr-inline">
    <div class="top-mid-float">
        <div id="main-inner-header">
            <h1><strong>Hello there!</strong></h1>
        </div>
        <div id="lower-content-header">
            <p>Quisque tincidunt nunc in lacus consectetur, et pharetra velit pulvinar. Quisque id egestas tellus, vitae venenatis tellus. Etiam accumsan iaculis sem, in vestibulum odio tincidunt vel. Etiam justo massa, congue vulputate dui.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As this is dynamic, the content in `top-mid-float` is always different.

This is in a string but if there's solutions from grabbing it from the DOM and then doing it I could work with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store the children of the `fr-element div`, remove everything from the row, and re-append the children:

```js
var $row = $('<div class="content fr-box fr-inline pixer row"><div class=fr-wrapper dir=auto><div class="fr-element fr-view"dir=auto aria-disabled=false contenteditable=true spellcheck=false><div class=top-mid-float><div id=main-inner-header><h1><strong>Hello there!</strong></h1></div><div id=lower-content-header><p>Quisque tincidunt nunc in lacus consectetur, et pharetra velit pulvinar. Quisque id egestas tellus, vitae venenatis tellus. Etiam accumsan iaculis sem, in vestibulum odio tincidunt vel. Etiam justo massa, congue vulputate dui.</div></div></div></div></div>');

var children = $row.find('.fr-element').children();
$row.empty().append(children);

// If you want to add the result somewhere
$('body').html($row);

// Or, to turn the modified result back into an HTML string
var finalHTMLString = $row.wrapAll('<div>').parent().html();
console.log(finalHTMLString);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @TomHeston, it actually already is, this (`var stringHTMLExample = $('.row')[0].outerHTML;`) converts it to a string from the DOM I had. But, I apologize, it's not that clear. I will update :)

Comment: @TomHeston, does that make more sense now?

Comment: Hi @KevBot thanks for this, last thing. How do I turn the $row into a string?

Comment: @TomHeston, do you mean back into a string of HTML, after you are done modifying it?

Comment: @TomHeston, You can do it by wrapping the result with another div and then getting the innerHTML from it. I demonstrated that above in the answer.

Comment: Hi @KevBot the only problem I'm having with this solution is that if there's another div that follows the same structure on the same page it inserts it also insert that div.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest option would be to chain the [`.unwrap()` method](https://api.jquery.com/unwrap/) twice:

```
$('.top-mid-float').unwrap().unwrap();
```

If you need to check to make sure that the correct element(s) are being unwrapped and removed, then you can specify the selectors for the parent elements if they are known in advance:

```
$('.top-mid-float').unwrap('.fr-element.fr-view').unwrap('.fr-wrapper');
```

---

This would also work if your HTML is provided in the form of a string (as stated in your comment).

You would just need to chain the `.find()` method in order to find the element `.top-mid-float`:

```
$($element_string).find('.top-mid-float').unwrap().unwrap();
```

Here is an example demonstrating this:

```js
var $element_string = $('<div class="content fr-box fr-inline pixer row"><div class=fr-wrapper dir=auto><div class="fr-element fr-view"dir=auto aria-disabled=false contenteditable=true spellcheck=false><div class=top-mid-float><div id=main-inner-header><h1><strong>Hello there!</strong></h1></div><div id=lower-content-header><p>Quisque tincidunt nunc in lacus consectetur, et pharetra velit pulvinar. Quisque id egestas tellus, vitae venenatis tellus. Etiam accumsan iaculis sem, in vestibulum odio tincidunt vel. Etiam justo massa, congue vulputate dui.</div></div></div></div></div>');

$($element_string).find('.top-mid-float').unwrap().unwrap();

$('body').html($element_string);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

Additionally, if the content is dynamic and you can't always select the `.top-mid-float` element, then you could go down to that level in the DOM by using:

```
$($element_string).find('> * > * > *').unwrap().unwrap();
```

You could also just use the `.children()` method in order to select immediate children elements at that level:

```
$($element_string).children().children().children().unwrap().unwrap();
```

Updated Example:

```js
var $element_string = $('<div class="content fr-box fr-inline pixer row"><div class=fr-wrapper dir=auto><div class="fr-element fr-view"dir=auto aria-disabled=false contenteditable=true spellcheck=false><div class=top-mid-float><div id=main-inner-header><h1><strong>Hello there!</strong></h1></div><div id=lower-content-header><p>Quisque tincidunt nunc in lacus consectetur, et pharetra velit pulvinar. Quisque id egestas tellus, vitae venenatis tellus. Etiam accumsan iaculis sem, in vestibulum odio tincidunt vel. Etiam justo massa, congue vulputate dui.</div></div></div></div></div>');

$($element_string).find('> * > * > *').unwrap().unwrap();

$('body').html($element_string);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @TomHeston - Yes, I updated the answer. Here is a [example](https://jsfiddle.net/yjwny3bm/) demonstrating this.

Comment: Thanks Josh, but would it be possible to use it without targeting .top-mid-float, because this might change?

Comment: @TomHeston this is great, last request, how can I turn $element_string back into a string of HTML?

Comment: @TomHeston - The [`outerHTML` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML) returns a string, therefore you could use `$element_string.get(0).outerHTML`.. Here is an updated example -> https://jsfiddle.net/j0u9jw6f/